# How to integrate leaflet tracksymbol plugin with angular?

Tags: angular, plugins, leaflet

I am using leaflet with angular. I installed leaflet with npm and imported it in my component with:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

Which works as expected. Next I installed the [leaflet-tracksymbol plugin](https://github.com/lethexa/leaflet-tracksymbol) via npm

```
npm install --save leaflet-tracksymbol
```

and imported it into my component:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-tracksymbol';
```

But when I try to create a tracksymbol with:

```
L.trackSymbol([lat,lng], options);
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'trackSymbol' does not exist on type 'typeof import("[...]node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.
```

I also tried to add the leaflet-tracksymbol.js to the angular.json script block and I tried to import it into my component with:

import '../../../../node_modules/leaflet-tracksymbol/leaflet-tracksymbol.js';

All three import methods seemed to wrok, but L is not extended and L.TrackSymbol not available.

I also tried to cast `(L as any).trackSymbol...` as an answer on SO suggested, that didtn work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. You need to install `@types/leaflet` as the error indicates.

```
ngOnInit() {
    var map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var latlng = L.latLng(20, 30);
    var speed = 10.0; // In m/s
    var course = (45.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0; // Radians from north
    var heading = (45.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0; // Radians from north

    var trackMarker = (L as any).trackSymbol(latlng, {
      trackId: 123,
      fill: true,
      fillColor: "#0000ff",
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      stroke: true,
      color: "#000000",
      opacity: 1.0,
      weight: 1.0,
      speed: speed,
      course: course,
      heading: heading
    });

    trackMarker.addTo(map);
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-integrate-leaflet-tracksymbol-plugin-with-angular-9fop3)